# Как использовать модальное окно авторизации Django на всех страницах сайта

Tags: python, django, modal

Я создал на сайте модальное окно авторизации при помощи django-bootstrap-modal-forms и django-widget-tweaks. Модальное окно открывается только тогда, когда пользователь находится на главной странице. Если перейти на любую другую страницу, то вызвать модальное окно не получится.
Я читал, что этого можно добиться при помощи context_processors.py, но не могу понять как и куда нужно вставлять код.
Я взял за пример код от модуля [django-bootstrap-modal-forms](http://trco.silkym.com/dbmf/), поэтому размещать в этом посте примеры кода нет смысла.
Есть ли способ осуществить мою задумку?

Вот примеры кода.
**views.py**

```
class SignUpView(BSModalCreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    template_name = 'authentication/signup.html'
    success_message = 'Вы успешно зарегистрированы. Авторизуйтесь.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('')


class CustomLoginView(BSModalLoginView):
    authentication_form = CustomAuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'authentication/login.html'
    success_message = 'Вы успешно авторизовались.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('')
```

**urls.py (в приложении)**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name='main'),
    path('upload/', views.upload_spectrum, name='upload'),
    path('display/', views.view_spectrum, name='display'),
    path('signup/', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login')
```

]

**forms.py**

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin, UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

**модальное окно авторизации login.html**

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form method="POST" action="" autocomplete="off">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Авторизация</h3>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">

    <div class="{% if form.non_field_errors %}invalid{% endif %} mb-2">
      {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger .alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <div class="text-left">
              <strong>Ошибка:</strong> {{ error }}<br />
            </div>
          </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
<!--        {% render_field field class="form-control" placeholder=field.label autofocus="" %}-->
        {% render_field field class="form-control" autofocus="" %}
        <div class="{% if field.errors %} invalid{% endif %}">
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <a href="/" class="forgot-password">Восстановить пароль?</a>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">Войти</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

**Файл _modal.html в котором вставляется js скриптом нужная форма (авторизация, регистрация)**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="create-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog mt-5">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog mt-5" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Скрипт в конце index.html, который отображает модальные окна**

```
{% block extrascripts %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          // Login
          $("#login-btn").modalForm({
            formURL: "{% url 'login' %}"
          });

          //  Signup
          $("#signup-btn").modalForm({
            formURL: "{% url 'signup' %}"
          });

           // Hide message
          $(".alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
              $(".alert").slideUp(500);
          });
      });
  </script>
{% endblock extrascripts %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы добавить свою переменную в контекст шаблона, вам нужно создать функцию в файле context_processors.py.

```
def modal_forms(request):
    return {'show_modal': request.path == '/'}
```

Далее, вам нужно добавить эту функцию в список context_processors в настройках Django:

```
# settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # ...
                'path.to.modal_forms',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: в каком месте использовать 'show_modal' из метода def modal_forms(request)?

Comment: И как связать этот метод с моими модальными окнами?

Comment: Aleksandr Fetisov, можете объяснить как настроить ваш пример контекстного процессора? Какое название ключа и метода нужно прописать? Я пробовал вставить в шаблон {{ show_modal }}, но в шаблоне у меня вывелось True текстом (на главной странице), если открыть любую другую страницу, то там будет выведено False..

Comment: я обновил код в вопросе, с учетом этого можно решить мой вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем разобрался сам, установил скрипт в base.html шаблон и туда же включил форму-шаблон модального окна, в котором отрисовываются разные формы, в зависимости от нажатой кнопки.